# Objective-c: Not getting the right text on NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

i am trying to catch some data on my plist , it has a lot of records

for that case i used this code

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"kurdiebg" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *plistData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"english = %@", self.searchQwery.text];
NSArray *filtered = [plistData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
NSLog(@"found matches: %@ : %@", filtered,[filtered valueForKey:@"kurdi"]);

NSString*nss = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[filtered valueForKey:@"english"]];
self.lblWord.text = nss;
```

its all fine on the Log, but on the uilabel it returns this
[image: simulator]

on the `NSLog`
[image]

Thanks

Comment: your matches are for "kurdi" don't for "english" you are printing with NSLog one thing and showing in your label another, please NSLog with "english", can you provide your plist content, to test your code?

Comment: It's because you use `valueForKey:`, which returns a `NSArray` and you use the `description` on it (it then "(\n someValue1,\n someValue2, \n)". You may have wanted: `NSString *nss = [[filtered valueForKey:@"english"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];`

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfHQ4.png), this is my plist image

Comment: @Larme , thank you so much man, you saved my life, got my left eye broken last year..because of using laptops a lot, you saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your filter is array od NSdictionary

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"kurdiebg" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *plistData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"english = %@", self.searchQwery.text];
    NSArray *filtered = [plistData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
    NSLog(@"found matches: %@ : %@", filtered,[filtered valueForKey:@"kurdi"]);
    NSString*nss = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[filtered valueForKey:@"english"]];

    if (filtered.count>0) {
        NSDictionary *dic  = filtered[0];
        self.lblWord.text = dic[@"english"];
    }
```